# After loading the site Next.js 14 to the hosting, loading.jsx does not work

Tags: next.js

loading.jsx does not work after launching the site on the hosting. Can you tell me what the problem is? When launched during development, everything works (`npm run dev`), but when building on the hosting (`npm run build`), loading.jsx does not appear on the screen at all, not even for a second. I read on the Internet that this is due to the fact that the hosting instantly creates this page and therefore the loading screen does not appear. Yes, I don't get any data from databases or anything like that. But I need this loading screen so that the picture on the main screen can load, and without a loading screen the picture simply does not have time to load and gradually appears before the user’s eyes.

loading.jsx

```
export default function loading() {
  return /*"Loading..."*/ (
    <div className='items-center self-center flex h-full'>
        <div className='items-center self-center'>
        <svg className='loading' width="200" height="304" viewBox="0 0 402 608" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M393.547 501.738L393.5 502.157V502.58V577.07C393.5 590.008 383.008 600.5 370.07 600.5H42.93C29.9921 600.5 19.5 590.008 19.5 577.07V493.93C19.5 480.992 29.9921 470.5 42.93 470.5H237C243.156 470.5 249.59 467.092 254.058 463.535C256.438 461.639 258.702 459.362 260.432 456.835C262.093 454.411 263.7 451.114 263.7 447.34V333.37V333.148L263.687 332.926C263.5 329.777 263.5 329.08 263.5 326.073V326C263.5 321.33 262.108 317.459 260.715 314.659C259.15 311.506 257.041 308.271 253.733 305.913C250.27 303.444 246.277 302.5 242 302.5L241.886 302.5C239.548 302.499 234.267 302.497 230.129 305.86C227.796 307.754 225.141 310.437 222.223 313.71L142.997 392.937L142.995 392.939C133.855 402.086 119.016 402.089 109.863 392.937L51.0755 334.149C51.0748 334.148 51.074 334.147 51.0733 334.147C41.9322 324.996 41.9322 310.164 51.0733 301.013C51.074 301.013 51.0748 301.012 51.0755 301.011L171.483 180.603L171.791 180.295L172.061 179.954C172.652 179.207 173.216 178.64 174.326 177.536C175.431 176.436 176.839 175.029 178.676 172.903L178.681 172.897L178.686 172.891C180.954 170.255 181.792 167.192 182.14 164.897C182.493 162.574 182.442 160.313 182.385 158.771L182.384 158.761L182.384 158.752C182.126 152.246 178.634 146.885 174.355 143.331C170.084 139.783 164.428 137.5 158.61 137.5H30.93C17.9921 137.5 7.5 127.008 7.5 114.07V30.93C7.5 17.9921 17.9921 7.5 30.93 7.5H163.07C176.008 7.5 186.5 17.9921 186.5 30.93V108.62C186.5 120.227 194.905 130.767 206.947 132.309L206.954 132.31C213.592 133.154 219.838 131.193 224.589 127.428L224.593 127.424C224.634 127.391 224.692 127.346 224.763 127.291C225.131 127.004 225.853 126.441 226.457 125.889C227.023 125.371 227.767 124.625 228.456 123.631L282.403 69.6833C291.554 60.5322 306.386 60.5322 315.537 69.6833L374.327 128.473C383.478 137.624 383.478 152.456 374.327 161.607L279.105 256.828C278.101 257.694 277.255 258.682 276.73 259.314C276.246 259.898 275.725 260.567 275.378 261.013C275.27 261.153 275.178 261.27 275.11 261.356L275.094 261.378L275.077 261.4C271.56 265.928 270.133 270.797 270.559 276.728L270.56 276.731C271.472 289.341 282.292 298.5 294.4 298.5H370.27C383.208 298.5 393.7 308.992 393.7 321.93V499.07C393.7 499.965 393.647 500.854 393.547 501.738Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="15" />
        </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

*I'm using next.js 14 and app directory*
The loading.jsx is located in the root (app/loading.jsx)

I searched on the Internet and came across the fact that this happens because the site does not receive any data from the outside and therefore the page is created instantly and does not require loading.

Comment: When you use npm run dev, the pages are not prepared. Therefore, the loading state will be displayed before the page is completed.

When you use npm run build, every static page is completed. Therefore, the loading state will not be displayed as you are not fetching data.

If you really want to show a loading spinner, create a new component with a z-index of 999, fixed and inset-0. Use setTimeout to set it as hidden. Therefore, the picture simply does have enough time to load.